# How Add image to JAR Java

Tags: java

This is My code below:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon10 = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader()("image/cake/2.jpg")).getImage().getScaledInstance(150, 150, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
```

Comment: Hi. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code or whatever you have done or tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: when reading your title it seems you're having to different problems?

Comment: please any buddy tell mi how i can use image in jar file.

Comment: You need to add image to jar file Or what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1393766

Answer (score 0):

First step: Put your image in a defined location in your JAR-file. If you put it into the src-folder, maybe your IDE or your build-tool will package it to the JAR automatically. Otherwise check the documentation of your IDE/build-tool, in which location you have to put it.

Second step: Access the file from your program. I assume you put it in the package (the path in your JAR) package1/package2 and the file is called dump.jpg. In that case you call:

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/package1/package2/dump.jpg")));
```

getClass().getResource(...) returns an URL for a resource on your classpath. You start the path in the classpath with a '/' and use the complete path/packages to your resource, separated by '/'.